# SQL Query select the last entry of each product

Tags: mysql, sql, nested

Good Morning,

I'm trying to develop a simple inventory system, however i have difficulties to only select the last entry of Each product (Component ; Ref).

[image]

My current query is :

```
SELECT component, ref, date, qty FROM $usertable WHERE (SELECT qty FROM $usertable HAVING max(date) ORDER BY component ASC, ref ASC LIMIT 0,1)
```

As you can see I'm not familiar with nested queries :/

Can somebody help me to figure out the solution please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a self join to get the last entry for each product

```
SELECT u1.*
 FROM 
$usertable u1
JOIN ( 
SELECT component, ref, MAX(date) date
FROM $usertable 
GROUP BY component, ref
) u2
USING(component, ref,date)
```

Comment: wow, thank you so much for your help, it's working perfectly. I have to learn the "u1.*" "u1" and the "u2" thing now ;)

Comment: One last Question, I'm sorry to bug you, How can i have the same query selecting the entry just before the last entry for each product (not the max date but the one before for each) Thank you Khalid.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT component, ref, date, qty FROM
( SELECT component, ref, date, qty FROM MyTABLE ORDER BY date DESC ) AS dummyTable
GROUP BY component, ref
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT component, ref, date, qty
FROM $usertable
ORDER BY date
```